# Compare with WP Meta Query

Tags: array

I've a situation with WP Meta Query.

```
$args_1 = array(
        'status' => 'active',
        'number' => 'all',
        'object_id' => array(2)
    );
```

I want to compare two 'object_id' in array above if 'status' => 'active' in both 'object_id' , So i want to understand if is possible to compare with WP Meta Query?

Thanks,